# O método excedeu o limite de 65.535 bytes

Tags: java, jsp

Eu tenho um arquivo JSP e qualquer linha de código que eu insiro, ele exibe o seguinte erro:

```
The code of method .. is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit.
```

O problema é que estou usando o OpenCMS, que é baseado em Java e XML.

E nesse arquivo é onde carrego todas as informações dos conteúdos do site.

Tentei separar o código com include, mas não adiantou nada.

```
<%@ include file = "/system/modules/com.br.teste.site/libs/class.teste.jsp"%>
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu possa fazer?

Comment: Vê se alguma dessas soluções te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5484253/540552